# Could not update the nuget package due to the Incompatibility

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, nuget-update

I could not update the `WindowsAzure.Storage` NuGet Package. It seems other package that probably depends on it, each time I update that package, I got the same error:

> Install failed. Rolling back... Updating 'Microsoft.Data.OData 5.6.2'
>   to 'Microsoft.Data.OData 5.6.4' failed. Unable to find versions of
>   'WindowsAzure.MobileServices.Backend.Tables,
>   WindowsAzure.MobileServices.Backend.Entity' that are compatible with
>   'Microsoft.Data.OData 5.6.4'.

Why do I get this and how can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why do I get this and how can I resolve this issue?

According to the nuget package of [WindowsAzure.Storage](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.Storage/4.3.0), you will find this package have a dependencies is `Microsoft.Data.OData (>= 5.6.2)`:

[image]

when you update the package `WindowsAzure.Storage`, the dependency package Microsoft.Data.OData (>= 5.6.2) also need to upgrade to 5.6.4.

However, the nuget packages `WindowsAzure.MobileServices.Backend.Tables` and  WindowsAzure.MobileServices.Backend.Entity' are dependent on `Microsoft.Data.OData (>= 5.6.2)`:

[image]

In this case, NuGet could not update the nuget package `WindowsAzure.Storage`.

**To resolve this issue**, you can use the option `IgnoreDependencies` when you update that package:

```
update-package WindowsAzure.Storage -IgnoreDependencies
```

Comment: But When I use that  command I got following error:NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.UpdatePackageCommand

Comment: How about uninstall that package, then reinstall that package with option -IgnoreDependencies?

Comment: Yes, reinstall that package with option -IgnoreDependencies works fine, but why update with that option not work?